# Kde Plasma Task Manager is Broken after an update in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde

This is the error I get for Kde plasma task Manager after an Update

```
Error loading QML file: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.taskmanager/contents/ui/main.qml:26:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "org.kde.taskmanager": Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/taskmanager/libtaskmanagerplugin.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/taskmanager/libtaskmanagerplugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN11TaskManager10TasksModel21requestVirtualDesktopERK11QModelIndexi)
```

But If I cd into the place the .so file is present
Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

Just update again and the problem should be solved. There was a problem with :

```
libkwinglutils
libkwinxrenderutils
libkwineffects
```

updating from 11 to 12 for the mentioned packages should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your package using this command

```
pkcon update
```

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: open terminal and type pkconf update. It works on my KDE NEON

Comment: "pkconf" is not even existing in my system. 2 closest hits: pkgconf and pkcon (neither installed). My system is:Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: oops sorry typo, it should be pkcon. Maybe you should install it first if you didn't have on your system

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if it had a line or two explaining what this does, how it fixes the problem OP described.